# Entity framework 6 fluent API, how to map navigation key to a view with composite key

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have 3 tables where Property has a foreign key to Dependent and Dependent has a foreign key to Main, causing a One-to-Many relationship for each of the tables. However I am only interested in the most recent record in Dependent and its Property records, thus i created a view v_Dependent which returns the most recent Dependant record grouped by MainId. This will enable a One-to-One relationship between Main and Dependant which is what I'm after, works with the code below.

I am eager loading all when loading Main objects, however after i switched to the view I may no longer eager load the records in the Properties collection of Dependent. The reason for this is that to map the view into a One-to-One relationship I had to add MainId to the composite key for Dependent. Now the foreign key from Property would have to contain the MainId as well to be able to load the collection, however I do not have MainId in the database table, nor do I want to.

My question is, do I have to create a view for Property as well to include the MainId and add this to the entity composite foreign key, or is there anything else I can do to map this using fluent API? Another option I'm currently using is explicitly loading the Property collection in my repository, however I was hoping fluent API could handle this for me. The commented out line is the config which worked for the whole graph while I treated the Dependent as a collection on Main. I am using the entities read only, so dont have to worry about storing back.

```
public class Main
{
    public int MainId { get; set; }

    public Dependent Dependent { get; set; }
}

public class Dependent
{
    public int DependentId { get; set; }

    public int MainId { get; set; }
    public Main Main { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class Property
{
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }

    public int DependentId { get; set; }
    public Dependent Dependent { get; set; }
}

public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Main> Mains { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Dependent> Dependents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Property> Properties { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Main>().ToTable("Main").HasKey(m => m.MainId);
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Dependent>().ToTable("Dependent").HasKey(d => d.DependentId).HasRequired(d => d.Main).WithMany(m => m.Dependents).HasForeignKey(d => d.MainId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Dependent>().ToTable("v_Dependent").HasKey(d => new {d.DependentId, d.MainId}).HasRequired(d => d.Main).WithOptional(m => m.Dependent);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Property>().ToTable("Property").HasKey(p => p.PropertyId).HasRequired(p => p.Dependent).WithMany(d => d.Properties).HasForeignKey(p => p.DependentId);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#CompositeKey and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After alot of digging I found out that the underlying issue is that entity framework is unable to map a One to Zero or One relationship using a foreign key instead of primary key. See https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/299

As a result I had to choose between changing the primary key of Dependent (which is currently a view and thus I could create an indexed view with all the limitations of such, but I have a subquery I cannot get rid of) or load the properties seperately. I chose the latter and changed the applcation to no longer have a navigation property and loading the properties when needed.